# Audio jack is being detected conversely. How to swap events?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

As I can see from `acpi_listen`, my audio jack is being detected as plugged when I unplugged it and vice versa.

```
$ acpi_listen
jack/headphone HEADPHONE plug # I just plugged jack off
jack/headphone HEADPHONE unplug # I just plugged jack in
```

Is there any way I can configure that `unplug` actually means `plug` so I could get my internal speakers and headphones working at the right time?

- Xubuntu, 16.04.01, 4.4.0-93-generic, pulseaudio, alsa driver

Comment: I have a similar issue with a vanilla install on a Mac Pro 6,1 2013 cylinder. When I plug in the head phone jack, it plays on the line out and vise versa. plugging in two headphones make one play.